Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11828 "Cannot Open"
void initializePlayer(Map<String, dynamic> songData) {
BetterPlayerDataSource dataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
  BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
  songData['manifestUri'] ?? '',
  drmConfiguration: BetterPlayerDrmConfiguration(
    drmType: BetterPlayerDrmType.widevine,
 cant play the audio files on ios.audiofile is of format mpd

I want to play the song on iOS.
